# IBM WebShpere Liberty 17.0 and EJB 2.0 compatibility

Tags: websphere-liberty

I have an application developed with EJB 2.0 and JMS. I use .xmi file to define bindings. Currently I am running application on WAS 8.5.5 ND and JDK 1.6. I already have evaluated migration from JDK 1.6 to JDK 1.8. But I am planning to upgrade WAS 8.5.5 ND to WAS Liberty 17.0. I would to understand can this be done without any changes? Is WAS LIberty support EJB 2.0 with JMS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual says "EJB 2.x API entity beans are not supported by Liberty. For persistence, the Java Persistence API (JPA) must be used instead."  You should run webspheres migration tools to analyze your application to see what work might be waiting for you to move from the traditional application server to Liberty:

https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/move-applications-liberty-using-migration-toolkit/

Comment: Thanks Covener, We are not using entity beans in our application. We are using only Session Beans and MDBs. The persistence is done using normal JDBC with DAO classes.